# Is it possible to let GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS point to non-service-account credentials?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform

Service accounts have .json key files that it is easy to point to so that google cloud applications use those credentials by setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

Is it possible to use the same environment variable but pointing it to a standard user account .json key file (like one belonging to my own gsuite account)?

Comment: What do you mean by G Suite user account key file? If you mean one containing client secrets, the answer is No.

Answer (score 5):

When you perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` a JSON file is created

- On Windows, this is %APPDATA%/gcloud/legacy_credentials/<USER_EMAIL>/adc.json
- On other systems, $HOME/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/<USER_EMAIL>/adc.json

If you set your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to this user credential file, it works; the credential of the user will be used.

If the users are the only one logged on their computer, you can also unset the env var. The same file will be automatically retrieved by the library (well-known location)

Comment: Using ~/.bashrc, add : GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/HOME_DIR/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/USER_EMAIL/adc.json"  << type "source~./bashrc" to reload.  If you'd like to customize this to your environment.